# Remove of unwanted characters in a column using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

[image]

I have a webscraped data that needs to be cleaned please
For values that is divided by character "-" I want to keep the value before the character "-".
For values like 5000000R (4000000)R, I want to keep the first value before the ones in parentensis.
And I also want to get rid of the extra characters like "IN", "R".
i am using pandas dataframe

Comment: `df['your_col'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')`. If you have a more complex logic, make sure to provide a [**reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and the matching expected output.

Comment: why not clean it BEFORE placing it in a file during the scraping phase